# Порядок выполнения тестовых файлов Codeception

Tags: php, codeception

Проблема состоит в следующем

Есть, например, форма регистрации с 5ю шагами.
На каждый шаг написан отдельный Cest файл (поскольку тестировать на каждой форме надо много)

И тут получается такая каша

```
RegOne.php
RegThree.php
RegTwo.php
```

Можно ли как-то Codeception (cli) сказать, что надо запускать в другом порядке файлы?

Comment: Попробуй заюзать аннотации.
Чекни тут https://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас гляну!

Answer (score 0):

Привожу пример как у меня заработало

Использовались группы (https://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Groups)

Для запуска

```
$ php vendor/bin/codecept run -g register
```

и в `*.suite.yml` файле объявил группу

```
groups:
    register:
        - tests/acceptance/RegOne.php
        - tests/acceptance/RegTwo.php
        - tests/acceptance/RegThree.php
```

Спасибо @4e4e4i за наводку

Comment: К сожалению, codeception все равно выполняет тесты сортируя по алфавиту. Иначе говоря, группа тут не поможет. Тесты придется называть `Reg1.php`, `Reg2.php` и т.д.